# Groovy script to check Job Running status inside a folder?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, directory, cloudbees

Need Jenkins Groovy Script Help!

**Jenkins build should look inside the particular folder which is having few jobs for its running status,if those are running ; terminate the current build. In case the status is idle; current build should run instead of terminate.**

Scenario: 
            **Folder A** contains **Job 1, Job 2, Job 3**
            **Folder B** Contains **Job x, Job y, Job z**

•   If job x or job y or job z got triggered it should check Folder A jobs whether anything is running or not, 
•   For e.g. ., if two jobs are running; for instance Job 1 and Job 2 is running, Job x should get into **queue/terminate** until or unless the Job 1 and Job 2 to get finished. 
•   Once the Job 1 and Job 2 gets finished; then Job x should run if the job was in queued state.

Thanks

Comment: Not really a full answer although I can elaborate if desired; why not just build your job in dependant stages? You can chain steps using stages, or use try/catch logic to skip portions you don't want run.

Comment: Thx., btw both the folder contains the independent jobs based on the templates. Actually i am new to the groovy world and also to the jenkins scripting. So i am looking for a short code snippet; ** Current build look inside for the particular folder which is having few jobs and check the status if it is running ; terminate the current build. **